# Barchart grouped by variable both count up to 100 percent

Tags: r

I try to get a bar chart grouped by 'Phase' and the percentages should be 100% per phase, so in total 200%. I have tried many things, but I don't succeed. Have looked at other questions but there very different data is used. If someone could help me out, that would really help me.

```
BEAdata %>% 
  count(Phase = factor(Phase), Activities = factor(Activities)) %>% 
  mutate(pct = prop.table(n) * 100) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Phase, y = n, fill = Activities)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') + 
    geom_text(aes(y = n + .2,    # nudge above top of bar
              label = paste0(round(pct, 2), '%')),    # prettify
              position = position_dodge(width = .9), 
              size = 3)
```

[image: Output]

[image: Data]

Comment: for your next question please dput your data, we will find it easier to help if we can recreate the data

Comment: also, have you tried position = 'stack'?

Comment: Please provide data as plain text not images (_e.g._ paste output of `dput(BEAdata)`).

Comment: You need a grouping factor for calculating `pct`. Right now you're calculated `pct` in relation to the full table, and you need to calculate it grouped by `phase`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a group to before you do your `prop.table()` calculation.

The only change is the `group_by(Phase)` line.

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)

BEAdata %>% 
  count(Phase = factor(Phase), Activities = factor(Activities)) %>% 
  group_by(Phase) %>%
  mutate(pct = prop.table(n) * 100) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Phase, y = n, fill = Activities)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') + 
    geom_text(aes(y = n + .2,    # nudge above top of bar
              label = paste0(round(pct, 2), '%')),    # prettify
              position = position_dodge(width = .9), 
              size = 3)
```